# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified, this error occurs while running the project

Tags: model-view-controller, membership

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: public ActionResult Login()

        {

            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)

            {

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MembershipDbContext", "Form3", "UserID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

            }



            return View();

        }